# How should I approach wrapping objects in composite shapes in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing, composition

I'm a mixtape designer, who took a long break to learn and get better. This is one of the last things that i cannot seem to find a decent tutorial for at all. In this image, i imagine the designer who made this, somehow used a distort, of a uzi submachine gun, the wrapper contents itself is obviously custom.

How on earth do you contour something to an uzi?

[image]

Second one, he uses dollar bills sort of mummified around what are supposed to be intestines. Its insane. Usually i experiment until i get something if i want to learn something. I dont even know where to start on these.

Any experts out there, any resources with tutorials for these type of effects?

[image]

Comment: I suggest you use a 3d program. I use Blender. Here is an example of a ribbon: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69462/how-would-i-create-a-ribbon-around-a-hat/118234#118234

Comment: I'm not sure the two examples are using the same effect. The first one looks like it's a traditional collage with a [displacement map](https://www.google.com/search?q=photoshop+displacement+map). The second looks like it was done in a 3D application as @LeoNas suggests.

Comment: I don’t think it’s 3d: the warps look like they all exist in different perspective planes and shadows look painted. 3d would give a more consistent result. A lot of warped layers with some experience would give you the same result: just start trying, learn perspective and lighting

Comment: Print paper > get toy uzi > wrap in paper > take picture > tweak... is one way to avoid dabbling in 3D :)

Comment: I think @curious nailed the technique for the first one. But I suspect it was merely wrapped and photographed (even a poor photo would work), then graphics added to the paper afterwards digitally. The second is merely liquify I think.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar artwork before wrapping a texture on the drapes of clothing. I did this using the "Liquify" tool on Photoshop and it works like a charm if you do it right and with patience.

This tutorial I found on Youtube explains it - [Link Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIfjdUP8-c4)

Hope this helps!